# What's differences between sql server reporting services and other report tools

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports, report

I'm a self taught student and I created some web application in ASP.NET using Entity Framework and SQL Server.

For reporting, I dynamically create database queries using Entity SQL. After pulling the result I show the result in HTML or some other format like Excel.

I would like to do some professional reporting, but I don't know which direction I should go.

I've heard about SQL Server reporting services, Crystal Report, Stimul Report and Fast report. Do they all do the same thing? I'm wondering which tools or technologies should I study and use?

Comment: If you are on the MS stack already, SSRS is a good first step (and the price is right--free). Long-term, we can't really tell you what the right choice is.

Comment: I think your question may be a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. You should try searching for tutorials, introductions, and comparison articles on the various tools you mention. If you have *specific* questions about the mentioned tools then SO *is* the place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

> Do they all do the same thing?

For 80%+ of use cases, yes.  But each product has its own niche and its own unique features.

SSRS is the clear choice in a pure MS development environment.  It benefits from the vast MS help and support infrastructure, and has numerous built-in integrations with other MS products like Excel and SharePoint

Crystal Reports has momentum and history on its side.  It has no less bugs than the others, but has numerous mature usergroups, forums, etc. that leave only a very slim chance that you will have any issues that others haven't already had, fixed, and posted answers to.  Additionally, many companies have stuck with it as their standard tools, since prior to SSRS, no products really threatened CRs position as market share leader.  (Not that SSRS immediately threatened CR, but because SSRS was given away free as part of SQL Server, it developed a large following on the principle that SSRS is typically "good enough" and doesn't require additional licensing after you've paid for SQL Server.

I'm not familiar with Fast Report, and my understanding of Stimulsoft Reporting is that it works well in environments that employ numerous types of data sources.

> I'm wondering which tools or technologies should I study and use?

Assuming you want a job working with these tools, the answer lies in the market you want a job in.  If your job market is hiring primarily for a particular reporting system, it is a no brainer:  Study the one that you local companies are mostly hiring for.  (Sounds obvious, but I constantly see young techies studying a particular product for academic reasons, and then get frustrated that local companies aren't interested in the product they've devoted their learning energy towards.)

If your job market is neutral (or you don't care where you get a job), I'd recommend sticking with the big players (SSRS, Crystal Reports are the players in the list you mentioned) because job are more plentiful there.

From there, pick the philosophy you are most comfortable with:  (Beware, generalizations ahead)
SSRS works best in MS-centric environments and is used more by upstart companies, due to its price.  If you like new development, smaller companies and startups, this is your choice.  (My opinion only:  SSRS is a growing product that is backed solidly by Microsoft.  It hasn't even reached its "golden age" yet, and will continue getting better in future SQL versions.)
Crystal Reports is seen much more in larger corporate environments with numerous databases, and long lists of legacy systems.  If you like larger corporate environments, and maintaining established systems, this is your choice.  (My opinion only:  Crystal reports had its golden age in the '90s, and is gradually declining in market significance.  It'll still be around for decades as a big player, but I don't see them ever regaining their '90s prominence.)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion tends to be for Crystal Reports when talking about "customer facing" reports: Invoices, Statements, Confirmations, etc

SSRS is my favoured solution for all tabular, number-centric reporting.

Comment: Additionaly, the learning curve with Crystal is a bit steeper. If you're familiar with Excel and .NET SSRS will be easier to get to grips with

Answer (score 0):

The only experience I have is with Crystal Reports.  They seem to be nice to use once you get used to the quirks.  Also if you want to print labels and such they are fairly robust.  Exporting to Excel is nice but not as amazing as SSRS.  I would use CR for a clientele that is somewhat savvy with computers.  They can modify the reports themselves which is nice.

Comment: You can modify SSRS reports using Report Builder 3.0, too ...